# Multi-user disk-less workstation using Beyond Trust PowerBroker Identity Services Open Edition (formerly Likewise)

Tags: active-directory, likewise

I am attempting to create a multi-user disk-less workstation environment where all workstations will use the same image from the same tftp boot server and use Windows active directory log-in credentials. It appears that multiple **local** users can log in from 2 or more stations without any issues. However,  when using active directory credentials logging in to the second workstation breaks the connection to the domain controller. Apparently there are some files being shared and clobbered. There are some sockets in /var/lib/pbis that I imagine are critical. I assume I need to isolate shared files in a `tmpfs`.

Is a multi-user disk-less active directory workstation environment achievable? If so do you have any recommendations on how to prevent the active directory connection from breaking?

I am using:

- Ubuntu 12.10
- Lubuntu desktop
- PBIS Open 7.0.6.935 - Stable Release

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this would be easy to do.

How are you handling machine credentials? From what I remember, each machine is joined to the domain by an account with appropriate credentials. During the join process, an account (not really any different from user accounts) is created for the machine, complete with a password that must be changed periodically (30days is the default, I think.). [This account is saved in the pbis registry (somewhere under /var/lib/pbis) and is supposed to only be accessible by root.] So if two machines try to use the same account, they will also need to make sure to stay in sync with this password.

The sockets in /var/lib/pbis are important. For instance, the pam_lsass library (loaded by anything using PAM, like sshd), will access the socket in /var/lib/pbis to communicate with the lsass service, which is a service that will talk to the DC.

I believe /var is supposed to be unique to each machine.